# iOS7 Background Fetch

Tags: background, ios7, fetch

I am trying to implement the new iOS7 app refresh. I don't think it's working properly.

I add into the `info.plist`

Required background modes - App downloads content from the network

In my main view controller,

1. `UIApplicationDelegate` is set as delegate
2. In `Viewdidload` I put in `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:1.0];`
3. I add the following method

   ```
   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
       performFetchWithCompletionHandler: 
       (void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler {
           NSLog(@"Refresh from Background");
   }
   ```

I plug in my iPhone and launch the app and then I got to Debug -> Simulate Background Fetch

The NSLog does not print. (If my app is in the foreground, it will put it in the background)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can review apple's demo code from below link

http://adcdownload.apple.com/wwdc_2013/wwdc_2013_sample_code/52012_ios_simplebackgroundtransfer.zip

i tried fetching data in background in my app. It is working fine.

Comment: you can find it in https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#  and search for ios_simplebackgroundfetch and simplebackgrdountransfer - these 2 should pop up inside WWDC 2013 samples

Answer (score 0):

You shoud add

```
[application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
```

in method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

also this method

```
 (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))
```

completionHandler should be added to your app delegate class, not UIViewController, see this tutorial: http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html

Comment: I have implemented it this way and it only works when i call if from Xcode (Simulate background fetch). I never got notification from device ...